# Bean references in spring integration context configuration

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to determine the reason why my bean reference isn't recognized when I use it in the parameter for a stored procedure in a Spring Integration stored procedure outbound gateway.  I have been able to put a service activator in between and create a new message with the bean as the payload and it works fine.  But why can't I use the actual bean?

Here is a snippet of code:

```
    <bean id="updateDataContentsMapper" class="org.companyname.connector.support.UpdateDataContentsMapper" depends-on="updateDataContents">
            <property name="updateDataContents" ref="updateDataContents"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="updateDataContents" class="org.companyname.connector.model.UpdateDataContents"/>   


    <int:channel id="update-sp-channel"/>
    <int:channel id="operation-completion-channel"/>
    <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
                id="01-update-data-contents-sp-gateway"
                request-channel="update-sp-channel"
                reply-channel="operation-completion-channel"
                data-source="dataSource"
                stored-procedure-name="usp_UpdateDataContents" >         
                <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="@vKeyValue"
                                                   direction="IN"
                                                   type="VARCHAR"
                                                   scale="100"/>
                <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="@nSeqNum"
                                                   direction="IN"
                                                   type="NUMERIC"
                                                   scale="20"/>  
                <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="@vMessageLog"
                                                   direction="IN"
                                                   type="VARCHAR"
                                                   scale="100"/>   
                <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="@vRC"
                                                   direction="OUT"
                                                   type="VARCHAR"
                                                   scale="30"/>                                                          
            <int-jdbc:parameter name="@vKeyValue" value="#{updateDataContents.vKeyValue}"/>   
            <int-jdbc:parameter name="@nSeqNum" value="#{updateDataContents.nSeqNum}"/>
            <int-jdbc:parameter name="@vMessageLog" value="#{updateDataContents.vMessageLog}"/>     
            <int-jdbc:parameter name="@vRC" type="java.lang.String" value="new java.lang.String"/>
            <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="updateDataContents" row-mapper="org.companyname.connector.support.UpdateDataContentsMapper" />
    </int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

I have found this to be rather difficult to determine what I need to have.

```
<int-jdbc:parameter name="@vKeyValue" value="#{updateDataContents.vKeyValue}"/>
```

or

```
<int-jdbc:parameter name="@vKeyValue" value="#{updateDataContents.getVKeyValue()}"/>
```

or

```
<int-jdbc:parameter name="@vKeyValue" value="updateDataContents.getVKeyValue()"/>
```

I know if I use a message payload, this works:

```
<int-jdbc:parameter name="@vKeyValue" expression="payload.getVKeyValue()"/>
```

If anyone has a link or can just give me some insight to this, I'd greatly appreciate it.  I think I have the syntax correct.  It must be something with the actual integration component or something I am missing.

Thank you,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to determine here your target: if you need just use the pre-defined value or calculate it each time the Stored Procedure Adapter receives the message.

The `value="#{updateDataContents.getVKeyValue()}` is a *Bean Definition expression* and it is evaluated only once at startup.

There is an `expression` alternative attribute in the `<int-jdbc:parameter>` which can be specified like this:

```
<int-jdbc:parameter name="@vKeyValue" expression="@updateDataContents.getVKeyValue()"/>
```

In this case the `vKeyValue` will be calculated for each Stored Procedure execution.

Comment: As always, thank you Artem.  That is exactly what I wanted to know.